# Configure Intellij code assistance with Jhipster and Spring

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, jhipster

Trying to configure Intellij 2020.1.3 Ultimate to use code assistance with Jhipster generated code & a Gradle project.

Example the @transactional, @Service debug and page statements are hi-lighted in red. So are some of the java classes.

[image]

The instructions [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-ide-idea/) suggest File > Project Structure > Modules > click on Spring and then the + sign. My screen is different to the 4th image in the instructions which has many Spring classes already listed under the jhipster tree.

[image]

My screen (after clicking the +).

[image]

How do I add code assistance for the Spring classes?

Comment: Right click to project name > `Add framework suport` > `Find and check Spring framework`

Comment: Have you tried File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... ?

Comment: Can you build project from Gradle in command line? Has Gradle import completed successfully? Is there a project available to check?

Comment: A gradle refresh seemed to do the trick

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I seem to have to keep going gradlew clean to keep avoiding duplicate classes. Not sure if related